# ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1, magento1.9.3

after update to new version **1.9.3**. the Uploader  is not working anymore. given below error.i  upldate my code but still the same.

> var uploader = new
>
> Uploader({"uploaderConfig":{"chunkSize":1073741824,"withCrede...

below is my code

```
class Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Edit_Tab_Images extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget {

    protected $_uploaderType = 'uploader/multiple';

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setValues($data);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->setChild('uploader', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_uploaderType)
        );

        $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
                ->setFileParameterName('image')
                ->setTarget(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image'));

        $browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
        $browseConfig
                ->setAttributes(array(
                    'accept' => $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg')
        ));


        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After lot of searching i found that **magento 1.9.3.0 they remove the flash uploader** so js file need to run  **uploader**  add these file in **head**

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: How to upvote 5 times?

Comment: @Arvind07 find 5 answer and upvote :D

Comment: I have found this answer 5 times till now. It always saves me :)

Comment: @QaisarSatti I am new in Magento and working to fix the same issue, in the console its showing me the error `MediabrowserInstance is not defined magento`. I don't know from where I can add the files in the head and also did not find these files in the folder structure. Can you please help me in this

Comment: @AnshulMishra check this solution also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142006/issue-in-admin-panel-after-supee-patch-8788-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually its very far from my knowledge. I have open the magento first time in my life today. And I am facing the issue in the cms > static block > insert image. While click on this insert image a pop up has opened and just show the directory structure at the left nothing else. And throw the error in console "MediabrowserInstance is not defined magento"

Comment: @AnshulMishra this is not concern with these solution you have to google like these https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=magento+wysiwyg+editor+not+showing+images%5C&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK737PK737&oq=magento+wysiwyg+editor+not+showing+images%5C&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64l2.14649j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=magento+wysiwyg+editor+not+showing+images

Comment: You save my day .
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**I solved this problem by adjusting the file permissions.**

Problem was that the above mentioned (new) Javascript files could not be loaded. A 403 error code has been thrown.

After setting file permissions on the directories

```
js/image/adminhtml/uploader
```

and

```
js/lib/uploader,
```

the upload button works correctly again!

Comment: This folder too: "js/mage/adminhtml/*"

Answer (score 1):

Whereabouts are we supposed to add:

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by **head**

Comment: this is supposed to add current extension page head area.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add this code I am use custom theme in Magento 1.9.3.8 Version. Please give me file path.