# Issue in Admin Panel after SUPEE Patch 8788 installation

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, patches, supee-8788, conflict

I have **Magento CE 1.9.2.4** installed along with **patches (5377,1533,4788 etc. almost all patches).**

This question also reveals issues that may/surely occur in any custom module involving Image uploads in their custom sections, rather than just core magento issues.

1. Now after I installed the latest patch 8788 through command-line, I am not able to open "Add/Edit" page of my custom module, which was working fine prior to 8788 installation.

I am getting below error when I try to open the "Add New Banner" page of my module:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setUrl() on a non-object in /home/site_user/public_html/app/code/community/My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Add/Tab/Image.php on line 57

The culprit line is as below:

```
$this->getUploader()->getConfig()->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image'))
```

2. Also I cannot see already uploaded product images in admin `Catalog > Manage Products > Any product > Images` section.

Below is the core `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader` class being called.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml media library uploader
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */

/**
 * @deprecated
 * Class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader extends Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple
{
    /**
     * Constructor for uploader block
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->getUploaderConfig()->setTarget(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/upload'));
        $this->getUploaderConfig()->setFileParameterName('file');
    }
}
```

Anyone let me know **how to fix this with least code changes as possible.**

Comment: Could you post the content of the `getUploader` method please ?

Comment: Please check, updated my question.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need the content of your `getUploader()` method in your `app/code/community/My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Add/Tab/Image.php` file

Comment: The `getUploader` method has just this. public function getUploader() {
        return $this->getChild('uploader');
    }

Comment: try to find out what sets the uploader child and post the corresponding code. It's probably using the old uploader block

Comment: It is using `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader`, updated my question and added block file used.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Can we move to chat for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47164/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-8788 - Possible Problems?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Please check both cases in the question before hastily marking it duplicate.

Comment: @VickyDev just solved it here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141775/referenceerror-uploader-is-not-defined-in-magento-1-9-3

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Even after applying the answer (adding js files through `local.xml`) I don't see the previously uploaded Product images, Uploader works fine now.

Comment: Please upvote this question so that it receives more attention and more answers to fix the Product Image display issue post 8788 installaton.

Answer (score 17):

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader` is deprecated on after SUPEE-8788 (and 1.9.3). Thus there are several backward incompatibility changes which breaks module using the uploader.

I first thought a small change would fix it but there's actually way more to do.

### Make a module using the gallery compatible with 1.9.2 and 1.9.3

So if you're a module provider, you don't want to have two different versions of your module for 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. Here's how to make your code compatible with both:

In your block `_prepareLayout` method you need to do the following:

Replace:

```
 $this->getUploader()->getConfig()
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
                'images' => array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
                )
            ));
```

With:

```
    if (class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract")) {
        // PATCH SUPEE-8788 or Magento 1.9.3
        $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
            ->setFileParameterName('image')
            ->setTarget($url);

        $browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
        $browseConfig
            ->setAttributes(
                array("accept"  =>  $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg'))
            );
    } else {
        $this->getUploader()->getConfig()
            ->setUrl($url)
            ->setFileField('image')
            ->setFilters(array(
                'images' => array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => array('*.gif', '*.jpg','*.jpeg', '*.png')
                )
            ));
    }
```

As you can see I'm using `class_exists` to check whether SUPEE-8788 or Magento 1.9.3 is applied.

Then in your `gallery.phtml` you need to replace:

```
var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php if ($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?>null<?php else:?><?php echo $_block->getUploader()->getJsObjectName() ?><?php endif;?>, <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
```

With:

```
<?php if (class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract")): ?>
    var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
<?php else: ?>
    var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php if ($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?>null<?php else:?><?php echo $_block->getUploader()->getJsObjectName() ?><?php endif;?>, <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then for the layout file, you can do it like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><file helper="module/getFlowMin" /></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file helper="module/getFustyFlow" /></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file helper="module/getFustyFlowFactory" /></action>
    <action method="addJs"><file helper="module/getAdminhtmlUploaderInstance" /></action>
</reference>
```

Replace `module` with your helper class identifier and in your module `Data.php` helper add the following:

```
protected function _isNoFlashUploader()
{
    return class_exists("Mage_Uploader_Block_Abstract");
}

public function getFlowMin()
{
    return $this->_isNoFlashUploader() ? "lib/uploader/flow.min.js" : null;
}

public function getFustyFlow()
{
    return $this->_isNoFlashUploader() ? "lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js" : null;
}

public function getFustyFlowFactory()
{
    return $this->_isNoFlashUploader() ? "lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js" : null;
}

public function getAdminhtmlUploaderInstance()
{
    return $this->_isNoFlashUploader() ? "mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js" : null;
}
```

Comment: also `setUrl` change with `setTarget`.

Comment: It works for csv file upload issue on Magento 1.9.3.8. Great!

Answer (score 3):

adding in @Raphael answer  you need to add three fixes

first fix

**Spacename_Moduelname_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Edit_Tab_Images.php**

```
protected $_uploaderType = 'uploader/multiple';
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('moduelname/gallery.phtml');
    ....
}
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
 $this->setChild('uploader',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_uploaderType)
        );

        $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig()
            ->setFileParameterName('image')
            ->setTarget(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/image'));

        $browseConfig = $this->getUploader()->getButtonConfig();
        $browseConfig
            ->setAttributes(array(
                'accept' => $browseConfig->getMimeTypesByExtensions('gif, png, jpeg, jpg')
            ));
     return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Second fix in **adminhtml/default/default/modulename/gallery.phtml** file

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
//]]>
</script>
```

third fix the js part **layout/module.xml**

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

files to fixes loaction

first fix
**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php**

second fix
**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml**

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you mention the files for fixes too.

Comment: @VickyDev added the filename too.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer, but this thing occurs in Core Magento product images, so where do I need to make the first two changes ? Magento ce 1.9.2.4 with patch 8788 installed.

Comment: yep you need to add those two  third one for custom module if js is not loading

Comment: @VickyDev added the file location too..

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what I needed. Keep this answer in this full form.

Comment: You don't need to change the `_prepareLayout` function because the old block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader` extends the new block `Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple` now. You can remove that step it's pretty much useless

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i added this for custom module. for default that is not my intension. also `setUrl` also give error. believe me from last two days i working this (1.9.3.0)  same task :P :D

Comment: @QaisarSatti, Can we move this dicussion to chat ? I still have some things I need to clarify.

Comment: But I see no link for moving to chat displays here.

Comment: @QaisarSatti see I've updated my code so it's compatible with both 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i never doubt you. you are great fast learner  :)  +1 from me ..

Comment: @VickyDev same here didn't seen for while i have to post on meta :P :D

Comment: @QaisarSatti Actually the code in the respective files you stated is same as the code you posted here, just the paths are changed. Still the product images cannot be viewed n Admin panel, why is that ?

Comment: @VickyDev can you able to browse the images? check the firebug what error are their?

Comment: No cannot browse images, as there aren't any images displayed even if uploaded previously jsut fine.

Comment: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' ...a_gallery_content', , {"image":{"label":"Base Image ","field":"product[image]"} /index....95f84f/ (line 3795, col 81)` this is the error I am getting in firebug. Please check this error on some other platform, as I am reverting this patch now.

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed - Image Upload issue after PATCH 8788 install of Magento version CE 1.7.0.2 - 1.9.2.4.**

> `I was able to fix it,Please Follow following instruction.`
>
> > Step >> 1: After installed security patch 8788 successfully, Please go to admin panel and **flush all Magento cache**. Then **Logout your Admin Panel** and **Relogin to Admin Panel**.
>
> Step >> 2: **Go to Index Management** and select all **reindex all data** after **flush all Magento cache once again**.
>
> Step >> 3: ***This very Important step,*** **Delete your browser cache(Ctrl+shift+Delete) history clear all browsing data from browser including cookies.**
>
> Step >> 4: Go to Catalog >> Product Management , **add new image of any product,now you can see everything work fine.**

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing your same Issue case 2.  In my case it was caused by this file being overwritten by a custom module:

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml**

I would suggest you check to see if you have a similar template overwriting the template for that block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` and if that is the case, apply the `Supee-8788` patch to the overwriting file.