# Difference between magento 1.9.3.0 and magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.3.0, magento1.9.3, magento1.9.3.1

Magento has just released community edition `1.9.3.1`.

What's the difference with `1.9.3.0`? Only bugfixes from previous release or also other modifications?

Are there any backward-incompatible changes?

Is it also safe to upgrade directly from Magento `1.9.2.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the release notes, the only known issue as of today is:

> You currently cannot upgrade to this version using Magento Connect
>   Manager. We expect to resolve this issue soon.

Here's the list of changes directly from the release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1931

> Bug fixes:
>
> - We restored the old tax calculation algorithm for shipping charges. The patch to apply new calculation will be available on request.
> - Resolved an issue with setting the session lifetime to 0.
> - The monthly cron job that cleans up the table that contains IP addresses and passwords runs properly.
> - All configurable product images are imported.
> - You no longer get an exception due to an undefined addCrumbs() method call.
> - Resolved the error Notice: Undefined index: session_expire_timestamp when accessing the storefront.
> - Values for drop-down label values are saved correctly.
> - The "Price as configured" for bundle products displays correctly in the shopping cart.
> - Auto-generated passwords are sent to new customers as expected.
> - The method Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::processingMethodResult()
>     accepts scalar and array values.
> - The default MySQL Full-Text search works as expected; it no longer returns all products.
> - Catalog price rules return the correct price. Indexers now update all products instead of skipping the last product updated.
>
> Security improvements:
>
> - Prevented a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) vulnerability by changing the form key when a customer signs out of
>     the storefront.
> - Prevented a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability when adding a category.

After checking it seems like there is only one security improvement in 1.9.3.1 that you can find here: https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/9750b55c021832514a25c92695d735d9 . Please note that this fix is not included in any security patch as of today. #2 in the list above seems to be a wrong copy/paste as a similar line was already in 1.9.3.0 release notes

So there's no known backward incompatible changes between 1.9.3.0 and 1.9.3.1 BUT there is a backward incompatible change between 1.9.3 and 1.9.2.4 you can find details here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142013/2380

And yeah it's totally safe to upgrade directly from 1.9.2.4