# Magento 1.9.3.1 Upload Buttons not working

Tags: upgrade, magento1.9.3.1

After upgrading to magento 1.9.3.1 the uploading image buttons stop working, I already read all sites on google until page 6 and found a lot of solutions but any works for me, I also did Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788, but no success.
The box of similar questions are also looked.

Comment: have you check console? is there any error showing there?

Comment: @Kul Yes, the console is clear, I notice that the onclick, in the button is empty too.

Comment: Yes Onclick will be empty. that's not problem. I guess there should be some JS error but you said there is nothing on console. Please try on another browser as well.

Comment: I already tried in FF, Safari and Chrome
[print 1](https://s28.postimg.org/6bzduqsh9/Screen_Shot_2017_01_26_at_12_08_34.png)

[print_2](https://s28.postimg.org/72s40iuul/Screen_Shot_2017_01_26_at_12_08_45.png)

Comment: Try flush js. Also if you are merging js files, try undoing this. Have you checked magento logs? var/log?

Comment: @KonradSiamro I already flush js, the js files are not merged, if I do this, the submenu does not appear, I already check var/log, but what to look for?

Comment: SUPEE-8788 may cause some errors for Magento 1.8 and higher. Have You read: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/security-patch-supee-8788-possible-problems and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142006/issue-in-admin-panel-after-supee-patch-8788-installation ?